# Base component of Spatial Velocity Jacobian for a Free-Floating Base Robot is all Zeros

Tags: drake

I am trying to find the end-effector spatial velocity Jacobian for a robot with a free-floating base. Due to the free-floating base, the jacobian should contain a base component and a manipulator comment (see https://spart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial_Kinematics.html#jacobians)

V_ee = end-effector spatial velocity 
J_b = base jacobian component 
J_m = manipulator jacobian component 
v = generalized velocities

V_ee = [J_b, J_m] v

Until now, I was using SPART toolbox to do this in Matlab (https://github.com/NPS-SRL/SPART) and now I am moving to Drake. I tried using **CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity** in the *MultiBodyPlant* and the manipulator Jacobian is correct when compared to SPART. However, the base component of the Jacobian is all zeros. This is different from what I expected and from SPART as for a free-floating base, the base velocities contribute to the end-effector spatial velocities.

An example reproduction of this issue can be found here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/vyas-shubham/DrakeTests/blob/main/freeFloating/computeJacobian.ipynb

I think I'm either doing one of these wrong while using Drake:

- Using the *CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity* wrong. This is unlikely as the manipulator jacobian is correct and the base frame is also correct (only 1 frame in URDF).
- Making a wrong URDF for calculating Jacobians for Free-Floating base. Maybe I need to specify differently in URDF a floating-base for Drake to include this in the Jacobian computation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is taking the Jacobian of the chaser relative to the target; there is no floating base between them (so the jacobian wrt to the floating base should, indeed, be zero).  I think, perhaps, that you want to make `frame_A=world_frame`?

```
postCaptureTargetJacobian = postContactPlant.CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity(context=postCaptureContext,
                                             with_respect_to=JacobianWrtVariable.kV,
                                             frame_B=target_frame,
                                             p_BP=np.zeros(3),
                                             frame_A=world_frame,
                                             frame_E=world_frame)
```

PS - I added this cell to your notebook to quickly inspect your kinematic tree

```
from IPython.display import display, SVG
import pydot
display(SVG(pydot.graph_from_dot_data(postContactPlant.GetTopologyGraphvizString())[0].create_svg()))
```

PPS - Thanks for curating the example in the notebook.  That made it easy for me to take a look.

Comment: Thanks! That does make sense. I see the mistake in my code/jacobian frames now. Changing frame_A=world_frame gives the same Jacobian as SPART toolbox for the floating base.